# Transfer byte to char in Java - in CMD

Tags: java, cmd, char, byte

If I transfer `byte` to `char` in Java, I have following problem:

In Netbeans is all O.K., but if I run program from Windows cmd I have a problem with charset. I don't know why.

What to do?

Code:

```
char tmp = (byte) charFromByteInt; // it's byte in int variable
```

[image]

Comment: Post a snippet which demonstrates your problem. The piece you have posted is most probably not the problematic section.

Comment: @SubOptimal Sorry, i edited post.

Comment: Could you please post the code here and not an image. **btw.** The piece you have posted in your question would not even compile, as a `byte` cannot be assigned to a `char`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guessed on your output image it's a charset problem.

following snippet return the same byte values for your input string.

```
String testString = "TEST for stackoverflow";

byte[] bytes = testString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
System.out.println("bytes = " + Arrays.toString(bytes));

bytes = testString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
System.out.println("bytes = " + Arrays.toString(bytes));
```

**output**

```
bytes = [84, 69, 83, 84, 32, 102, 111, 114, 32, 115, 116, 97, 99, 107, \
         111, 118, 101, 114, 102, 108, 111, 119]
```

As your output in the console generates more characters then in the input string, you should check the source (from where you take the `byte` / `int` values) for the output.